# Is it possible to generate interfaces with Swagger codegen if Java&RestTemplate

Tags: java, resttemplate, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate APIs with Swagger CodeGen but when I am using Java and RestTemplate as language and library the ApiClient is not implementing an interface.. for other reasons that is required for me.

With the same configuration, just with Sprint & SpringBoot it is working.

Is it possible somehow with some config changes?